# pineapple houseplant tipped and stem disturbed at ground level

Tags: indoors, pineapple

When returning my pineapple plant to its usual spot, the central stem almost snapped at ground level.  I propped up the plant with a stake, but want to know if there is anything else to do to ensure the plant recovers.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have pictures maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Since this pineapple has a central stem you seem to be indicating that it has reached maturity and has produced a stem with a heavy pineapple fruit on top, and this weight with its leverage has caused the break during the move. So we know that basically, despite the unfortunate break the plant has come close to end of life, will continue to ripen the fruit, produce pups at the side at soil level and the centre will die out shortly.

The staking is a good idea and will likely carry the plant through to the end. It will keep the fruit clear of the soil. Likely there will be enough resources in the thick stem to continue to nourish the fruit to the end despite the break unless it has become completely separated. Once removed from the mother plant the fruit cannot ripen much more than it already is.

Once the fully mature fruit can be separated from the mother plant the broken stem can be removed (eliminating the need for the support stick) and composted, then focus on allowing the pups to gain some traction so that they can be cut off and repotted separately to start the new round of plants.